# Ignoring null values in columns. pivot and unpivot

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2012, pivot, unpivot

I have below data format

[image]

I am looking for below data format

[image]

I try all options but unable to reach the below result.

Query :

```
      create table dbo.FS_Daily_HSE_SAPS_Audit(
  formId int default 2934,
  form_Description nvarchar(50) default 'Daily_HSE_SAPS_Audit',
  submittedFormId int default 63917,
  actions nvarchar(30),
  Avalue nvarchar(30),
  ObservationDescription nvarchar(50),
  ObservationValue nvarchar(50),
  isVersion int default(0)
);
```

Insert :

```
insert into dbo.FS_Daily_HSE_SAPS_Audit(actions, Avalue,
  ObservationDescription, ObservationValue) values
  ('ACT/CONDITION-2', 'Condition', NULL, NULL),
  ('OBSERVATION-DESCRIPTION-2', '', NULL, NULL),
  ('SAFETY-DEFICIENCY-2', 'Act', NULL, NULL), 
  (NULL, NULL, 'OBSERVATION-DESCRIPTION-3', cast(newid() as nvarchar(50))),
  (NULL, NULL, 'ACT/CONDITION-3', cast(newid() as nvarchar(50))),
  (NULL, NULL, 'SAFETY-DEFICIENCY-3', cast(newid() as nvarchar(50)))

;


select
  a.formId, a.form_Description, a.submittedFormId, a.actions, a.Avalue,
  b.ObservationDescription, b.ObservationValue, a.isVersion
from dbo.FS_Daily_HSE_SAPS_Audit as a
inner join dbo.FS_Daily_HSE_SAPS_Audit as b
  on right(a.actions, 1) = right(b.ObservationDescription, 1);
```

Comment: If you need help on query, please post the query, DDL of underlying table with above two details i.e. current result and expected result. Please check this thread - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51278149/how-to-remove-null-values-from-an-sql-pivot

Comment: My query return nothing

Comment: two unpivot return nothing

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do you really need PIVOT operators?
**1)**

```
select
  a.formId, a.form_Description, a.submittedFormId, a.actions, a.Avalue,
  b.ObservationDescription, b.ObservationValue, a.isVersion
from dbo.FS_Daily_HSE_SAPS_Audit as a
inner join dbo.FS_Daily_HSE_SAPS_Audit as b
  on right(a.actions, 1) = right(b.ObservationDescription, 1)
;
```

Results:

```
+--------+----------------------+-----------------+-----------------+-----------+---------------------------+--------------------------------------+-----------+
| formId |   form_Description   | submittedFormId |     actions     |  Avalue   |  ObservationDescription   |           ObservationValue           | isVersion |
+--------+----------------------+-----------------+-----------------+-----------+---------------------------+--------------------------------------+-----------+
|   2934 | Daily_HSE_SAPS_Audit |           63917 | ACT/CONDITION-3 | Act       | OBSERVATION-DESCRIPTION-3 | 77C81C5F-8AFD-4FC6-975F-E1C3AA85C956 |         0 |
|   2934 | Daily_HSE_SAPS_Audit |           63917 | ACT/CONDITION-4 | Condition | OBSERVATION-DESCRIPTION-4 | B80E24D5-B25F-415E-A9A7-9271A466E08F |         0 |
|   2934 | Daily_HSE_SAPS_Audit |           63917 | ACT/CONDITION-2 | Condition | OBSERVATION-DESCRIPTION-2 | 85F1BB30-17AD-49D8-911F-8D5170663B34 |         0 |
|   2934 | Daily_HSE_SAPS_Audit |           63917 | ACT/CONDITION-5 |           | OBSERVATION-DESCRIPTION-5 | 73226A46-3ED2-48CA-91A9-B17BCFF4E5BB |         0 |
|   2934 | Daily_HSE_SAPS_Audit |           63917 | ACT/CONDITION-1 | Act       | OBSERVATION-DESCRIPTION-1 | 06B125D8-FED6-41EA-8E40-04A407A73FFC |         0 |
+--------+----------------------+-----------------+-----------------+-----------+---------------------------+--------------------------------------+-----------+
```

**2)**

```
select
  a.formId, a.form_Description, a.submittedFormId, a.actions, a.Avalue,
  b.ObservationDescription, b.ObservationValue, a.isVersion
from dbo.FS_Daily_HSE_SAPS_Audit as a
inner join dbo.FS_Daily_HSE_SAPS_Audit as b
  on left(a.actions, charindex('-', a.actions)) =
     left(b.ObservationDescription,
          charindex('-', b.ObservationDescription))
;
```

Results:

```
+--------+----------------------+-----------------+---------------------------+-----------+---------------------------+--------------------------------------+-----------+
| formId |   form_Description   | submittedFormId |          actions          |  Avalue   |  ObservationDescription   |           ObservationValue           | isVersion |
+--------+----------------------+-----------------+---------------------------+-----------+---------------------------+--------------------------------------+-----------+
|   2934 | Daily_HSE_SAPS_Audit |           63917 | ACT/CONDITION-2           | Condition | ACT/CONDITION-3           | 516F0218-1A71-40D0-A730-318A6E4DD1E3 |         0 |
|   2934 | Daily_HSE_SAPS_Audit |           63917 | OBSERVATION-DESCRIPTION-2 |           | OBSERVATION-DESCRIPTION-3 | 952382B3-CCDF-4889-B8FC-86A80296CAC6 |         0 |
|   2934 | Daily_HSE_SAPS_Audit |           63917 | SAFETY-DEFICIENCY-2       | Act       | SAFETY-DEFICIENCY-3       | 7310BA10-6945-4108-92CE-90CF7F00ED21 |         0 |
+--------+----------------------+-----------------+---------------------------+-----------+---------------------------+--------------------------------------+-----------+
```

[Demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2012&fiddle=e3d36900aca501787ff818341b091029).
The table of results has been created [here](https://senseful.github.io/text-table/).

Comment: I am ok with other options. I tried with Inner Join, Cross apply but null value appears all-time in the new row.

Comment: Bingo... Its' look like work for me. Thank you

Comment: Will you please explain me that what is mean of this last line. on right(a.actions, 1) = right(b.ObservationDescription, 1)

Comment: This query is a prototype. If I need to enhance with multiple columns then what to do? when I run here. then right(a.Avalue1)=right(b.Observationvalue,1) worked

Comment: The last line of the query is an [equi join](https://www.w3resource.com/sql/joins/perform-an-equi-join.php) condition to [join the table with itself](https://www.geeksengine.com/database/multiple-table-select/self-join.php). This condition is my guess about the conditions you can use. Additional data samples could provide more information to give a more accurate answer.

Comment: Hey, I updated the real data form. the last compare equation return nothing

Comment: Your data looks to me as exceptionally skewed.

Comment: I have done it. with left join.

Answer (score 0):

The most important is the Right() comparison `"where"` the condition. I used the left join function. and its work

```
 select
  a.formId, a.form_Description, a.submittedFormId, a.actions, a.Avalue,
  b.ObservationDescription, b.ObservationValue, a.isVersion
from dbo.FS_Daily_HSE_SAPS_Audit as a
inner join dbo.FS_Daily_HSE_SAPS_Audit as b
  on left(a.actions, len(a.actions)-1) =
     left(b.ObservationDescription, len(b.ObservationDescription)-1)
;
```